# Creating a dynamic Sql query for Client specific mail templates

Tags: java, sql, spring, postgresql, spring-boot

**Problem Statement**: I am creating client-specific email templates, where when client choose to add a template of its own, a blank page will open, where he/she can start writing an email of own, but can also choose from a list of **placeholders**
for ex:

```
Hi <studentname>
```

and there are many more placeholders

**What is expected is**:

> we replace those placeholders at runtime, with actual data from the
> database
>
> It can be done with help of primary keys in the database.

But the problem is, each of the clients can choose different no of placeholders and then it will end up with a lot number of SQL queries.

Is there any way to optimize this?

Comment: see stored procedures, they are helpful for processing data in sql and they might be suitable for you case.

Comment: @atish.s Thanks for the response:), though I will be using stored procedure, still I will have to write that many queries?

Comment: my apologies for the late reply, if you don't want to deal with sql queries, you can use Thymeleaf for creating email templates. You can use one table to store the template with placeholders for values and another table to store the values for the placeholders. For more info check: https://javabydeveloper.com/spring-boot-email-template/